# React native: Add multiple environments to sentry using expo

Tags: react-native, expo, sentry

I want to configure Sentry in a React native app to report errors using different environments, like development and production

How can I configure different environments?

```js
Sentry.init({
  dsn: 'asdfg',
  enableInExpoDevelopment: false,
  debug: true
});
```

Comment: You can simply add `environment: "your_environment"` in your configuration. For example: `Sentry.init({environment: "production"});` https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/react-native/configuration/environments/

Comment: @UgurEren can i add multiple environment for example production and development?

Comment: Yes, you can. https://docs.sentry.io/product/sentry-basics/environments/ `Environment tag accepts any value, but it's intended to refer to your code deployments' naming convention, such as development, testing, staging, or production.`

Comment: @UgurEren like Sentry.init({environment: {"production", "development"}})?

Comment: No, you can only set 1 environment at a time. You can use the `__DEV__` global variable to determine if you're on development environment. `Sentry.init({environment: __DEV__ ? 'development' : 'production'});` this will set the sentry's environment to development if you're on development environment, or set to production if you're not.

Comment: @UgurEren I will try. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can try a kind of switch case in your environment object Sentry.
eg. if env === dev 'development'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).